# yahoo finance ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, yahoo

Just used fiddler to get this ajax call for updating the NASDAQ prices:

http://streamerapi.finance.yahoo.com/streamer/1.0?s=^IXIC,USD=X&o=APWR,CCGM,CTFO,GNMK,HRBN,JRJC,MCBF,RIMM,YUII,ZOOG,^FTSE,^DJI,^GSPC,^IXIC,^TYX,^RUT,CLN11.NYM&k=c10,g00,h00,l10,p20,t10&j=c10,l10,p20,t10&r=0&callback=parent.yfs_u1f&mktmcb=parent.yfs_mktmcb&gencallback=parent.yfs_gencb&region=GB&lang=en-GB&localize=1&mu=1

When i put it in a browser i (obviously?) dont see anything. How can i go about seeing the data which updated the price on the yahoo finance page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can view the raw output using Fiddler. You don't need a browser.